# Force on a moving charge in front of an infinite conducting wall

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, forces, conductors

Let's say we have a charge $q$ at position $\vec{x}=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ in front of an infinite conducting wall at $z=0$. If the charge is not moving, this problem can be easily solved by the method of images: A charge $-q$ at position $\vec{x}=(x_0,y_0,-z_0)$ gives the correct electric field (outside the conductor) generated by the surface charge on the wall.

Now, let's say the particle is moving in a fixed path along the $\hat{x}$ direction. the particle is fixed on this path for simplicity, so it won't be moved by external forces. If I understand correctly, the method of images can still be used. The charge distribution that gives the correct boundary conditions on the wall is still a charge $-q$ on the reflected position.

I wanted to calculate the force that the moving charge $q$ feels in presence of the conducting wall but I encountered a problem: Different methods yield different answers.

**Method 1: Boosting the static problem**

We can start with the covariant equations of motion

\begin{equation}
\frac{d p_\mu}{d\tau}=\frac{q}{c}F_{\mu\nu}u^\nu
\end{equation}
where $p_\mu=m u_\mu$ is the 4-momentum, $u^\mu=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}$ is the 4-velocity and $F_{\mu\nu}$ is the Maxwell EM tensor.

Without going into too much detail, if I boost this equation starting from the static case. I get a force that has both a $\hat{x}$ and a $\hat{z}$ components.

**Method 2: Using the Liénard–Wiechert potential of the Image charge**

If I use the LW potential of the image charge and calculate the force it excerts on our charge $q$ I get that the force has only $\hat{z}$ component. This makes sense since the electric field derived from the LW potential points in the direction of the actual position of the charge, not the retarded one.

So the question is: If a charge $q$ moves in the $\hat{x}$ direction at constant speed in front of a conducting wall at $z=0$, what is the direction of the force the wall excerts on the charge? Is it perpendicular to the wall? Or does it have a component in the direction of the charge's movement as well?